# How to make my two input calculations, each outputs a different color for the result?

Tags: javascript, html

Basically, in the function, I'm trying to get each type of calculation to show the result in their own unique color. But, when I try the calculation, they all appear as orange when the orange should only be for addition. For subtract, it should come out as blue, multiplication it should be red and division should be green.

How do I solve the problem?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

function addBy()
  {
    var num1, num1, res;
    num1=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum1.value);
    num2=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum2.value);
    res=num1+num2;
    document.formcalc.txtres.value=res;
  }
 
function subtractBy()
{
 var num1, num1, res;
 num1=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum1.value);
 num2=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum2.value);
 res=num1-num2;
 document.formcalc.txtres.value=res;
}
  
function multiplyBy()
{
 var num1, num1, res;
 num1=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum1.value);
 num2=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum2.value);
 res=num1*num2;
 document.formcalc.txtres.value=res;
}

function divideBy()
{
 var num1, num1, res;
 num1=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum1.value);
 num2=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum2.value);
 res=num1/num2;
 document.formcalc.txtres.value=res;
}

  document.getElementById("txt_AddBy").style.color = "#ffa500";
  document.getElementById("txt_subtractBy").style.color = "#0009ff";
  document.getElementById("txt_multiplyBy").style.color = "#ff0000";
  document.getElementById("txt_divideBy").style.color = "#00ff00";


</script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Calculate</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form name="formcalc">
 Number 1: <input type="text" name="txtnum1">
 <br>
 Number 2: <input type="text" name="txtnum2">
 <br>
 Answer : <input id="txt_AddBy" id="txt_subtractBy" id="txt_multiplyBy" id="txt_divideBy" type="text" name="txtres" disabled="disabled"/> <br>
  
 <input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addBy()"/>
 <input type="button" value="Subtract" onClick="subtractBy()">
 <input type="button" value="Multiply" onClick="multiplyBy()">
 <input type="button" value="Divide" onClick="divideBy()">
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot give a single element multiple `id`s. Use a single id only (or just refer to the element by name, as you already do). Then assign the style in the respective click handler, not once on document load.

Comment: Don't do that **id="txt_AddBy" id="txt_subtractBy" id="txt_multiplyBy" id="txt_divideBy"**. **ID** must be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why having these too many functions when you can make it with only one ?

How would we do that with only one function that will be applied to all the `button`s (in fact `input[type="button"]` you had in your code anyway) :

- the `HTML` won't have these `onClick` in the `button`s, instead `JavaScript` will take care of the click event as that's the recommended way.
- two `data-*` attributes will be added :

  - `data-operator`: which defines the operation of the `button` (add, multiply...) and it can be `+`, `-`, `*` or `/` (`JavaScript` will know which operation should take place when a `button` is clicked).
  - `data-color`: which has the color (orange for addition...) of the result `input` (I wonder why you used a disabled `input` to show the result !).
- one helper function and an `object` that are used in order to get the right result and color :

  - `operators`: which is an `object` containing the four fundamental operation (addition, subtraction...) as a function for each operation. The use of an operation is based on the `data-operator` of the `button` that was clicked.
  - `calculate`: is the function that calculates the result and adjusts the color based by using the `operators` `object` and the `data-color` of the `button` that is clicked.

Let's not make any longer, here's a working example, it has a wealth of helpful comments that may assist you while reading the code :

```js
/**
* btns: the operations buttons (input[type="button"] you used).
* numOne: the "#num-1" input.
* numOne: the "#num-2" input.
* res: the "#result" input.
* operators: the object having the fundamental operations.
* calculate: the function that calculates and prints the result. CAUTION this function doesn't check if the inputs (numOne and numTwo) have a valid numbers, a "NaN" text will be printed in that case.
**/
const btns = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=button]')],
  numOne = document.getElementById('num-1'),
  numTwo = document.getElementById('num-2'),
  res = document.getElementById('result'),
  operators = {
    '+': (x, y) => {return x + y;},
    '-': (x, y) => {return x - y;},
    '*': (x, y) => {return x * y;},
    '/': (x, y) => {return y !== 0 ? x / y : 0;}
  },
  calculate = (op, color) => {
    /** calculate the result based on the operation from the data-operator of the button being clicked using the "operation" object **/
    /** the plus sign "+" in front of "numOne.value" (and the other one) is used to convert the inputs values to integers (without no any Number or parseInt) **/
    res.value = operators[op](+numOne.value, +numTwo.value);
    /** change the color based on the color from the data-color of the button being clicked **/
    res.style.color = color;
  };

/** cycle through the buttons and attach a click event handler for each one **/
/** addEventListener function adds a click event handler to each button **/
btns.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', () => calculate(el.dataset.operator, el.dataset.color)));
/** call the "calculate" function and send in the parameters the data-operator and the data-color of the button that is clicked  **/
```

```html
<!--removed the IDs on the buttonsand added the "data-*" attributes -->
<!-- the IDs of the inputs for the number are changed (not a big deal, make sure to change them in the "JavaScript" part as well if you want to change them) -->
<form name="formcalc">
  Number 1: <input type="text" id="num-1" name="txtnum1">
  <br> Number 2: <input type="text" id="num-2" name="txtnum2">
  <br> Answer : <input id="result" type="text" name="txtres" disabled="disabled" /> <br>

  <input type="button" data-operator="+" data-color="#ffa500" value="Add" />
  <input type="button" data-operator="-" data-color="#0009ff" value="Subtract" />
  <input type="button" data-operator="*" data-color="#ff0000" value="Multiply" />
  <input type="button" data-operator="/" data-color="#00ff00" value="Divide" />
</form>
```

**Some helpful links :**

> Learn more about [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) function.
>
> Learn more about [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) function.
>
> Learn more about [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my ***simple solution***  check the below given code:

```
document.getElementById("txt_AddBy").style.color = "your_color";
```

Just include the above line inside the function so u can apply different color for each function easily.

```js
function addBy()
{
var num1, num1, res;
num1=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum1.value);
num2=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum2.value);
res=num1+num2;
document.formcalc.txtres.value=res;
document.getElementById("txt_AddBy").style.color = "orange";
}

function subtractBy()
{
var num1, num1, res;
num1=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum1.value);
num2=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum2.value);
res=num1-num2;
document.formcalc.txtres.value=res;
document.getElementById("txt_AddBy").style.color = "green";
}

function multiplyBy()
{
var num1, num1, res;
num1=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum1.value);
num2=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum2.value);
res=num1*num2;
document.formcalc.txtres.value=res;
document.getElementById("txt_AddBy").style.color = "blue";
}

function divideBy()
{
var num1, num1, res;
num1=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum1.value);
num2=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum2.value);
res=num1/num2;
document.formcalc.txtres.value=res;
document.getElementById("txt_AddBy").style.color = "red";

}
```

```html
<form name="formcalc">
Number 1: <input type="text" name="txtnum1">
<br>
Number 2: <input type="text" name="txtnum2">
<br>
Answer : <input id="txt_AddBy"  type="text" name="txtres" disabled="disabled"/> <br>

<input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addBy()"/>
<input type="button" value="Subtract" onClick="subtractBy()">
<input type="button" value="Multiply" onClick="multiplyBy()">
<input type="button" value="Divide" onClick="divideBy()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify Js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
const color_addition = "#ffa500";
const color_subtraction = "#0009ff";
const color_division = "#ffa500";
const color_multiplication = "#ff0000";
function addBy()
  {
    var num1, num1, res;
    num1=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum1.value);
    num2=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum2.value);
    res=num1+num2;
    setAnswer(res,color_addition);
  }

function subtractBy()
{
    var num1, num1, res;
    num1=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum1.value);
    num2=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum2.value);
    res=num1-num2;
    setAnswer(res,color_subtraction)
}

function multiplyBy()
{
    var num1, num1, res;
    num1=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum1.value);
    num2=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum2.value);
    res=num1*num2;
    setAnswer(res,color_multiplication);
}

function divideBy()
{
    var num1, num1, res;
    num1=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum1.value);
    num2=Number(document.formcalc.txtnum2.value);
    res=num1/num2;
    setAnswer(res, color_division);
}

function setAnswer(res, color)
{document.getElementById("txt_Answer").style.color = color;
document.getElementById("txt_divideBy").value = res;
}

  window.load = function(){
 document.getElementById("txt_AddBy").style.color = color_addition;
  document.getElementById("txt_subtractBy").style.color = color_subtraction;
  document.getElementById("txt_multiplyBy").style.color = color_multiplication;
  document.getElementById("txt_divideBy").style.color = color_division;
 }

</script>
```

Modify Html: change the id of answer element to 'txt_Answer'. And also note that an element can only have just one id

```
Answer : <input id="txt_Answer" type="text" name="txtres" disabled="disabled"/> <br>
```